# var_export to string

Tags: php, string, render-to-string

I have an HTML code in the `$output` string, this code is delimited by two terms: `-startMiniPreview-` and `-endMiniPreview-`.
I need to take the part wrapped between those two terms and save it in another string variable.
This is what I thought was the right way to do so, but it's not working at all. The `HTMLCODE` part is getting exported succesfully but not as a string

```
    $output="-startMiniPreview-HTMLCODE-endMiniPreview-EXTRA";
    preg_match( '/\-startMiniPreview-(.*?)\-endMiniPreview/', $output,$vt);
    $cutOut=strval(var_export($vt[1]));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/var-export) clearly gives the answer:

```
$cutOut = var_export($vt[1],true);
```

EDIT: That said, why are you doing this? Just `$cutOut = $vt[1];` is all you need.

Comment: This actually worked.
Silly me, I'm still a newb at PHP, but I just found out it's not complicated as I guessed.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to var_export makes it return the string instead of outputting it directly http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

```
mixed var_export ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )
```

So your code should look like

```
$cutOut=strval(var_export($vt[1]), TRUE);
```